# Center div on mobile view

Tags: html, css

I've made a project in which I centered a div with its content of image by width 50% and left margin 25%. For windows view it was perfect but when I hosted the website it's content on my mobile weren't very present and attractive as it was in a thin box and that 50% width wasn't looking great on mobile. What should I do?

I centered div my 50% of my width but I wanted it to look good on mobile but I want to make it around 70-80% on mobile and still want it to look good on mobile

Comment: There is [responsive design](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design) and [user agent sniffing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent). 

Comment: And try `margin: 0 auto` on the `div` to center it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use different property values on a desktop and a phone you should use `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)`, in which u define style for phones. In this example, it will be activated if the screen width is less then 600px.

Final CSS might look like this

```
.myDiv{
    width: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .myDiv {
        width: 80%;

        /*center div*/
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use different property use `@media screen and (max-width:991px){}`

in this you can apply  flex with justify-content  for calculating the width use max-width with width:100% result give accurate result and if you want to show it in column use flex-direction:column and for managing the center try margin:0 auto

```
@media screen and (max-width:991px){
   display:flex;
   justify-content:center;
   margin:0 auto;
   flex-direction:column; //your choice
   max-width:80%;
   width:100%;

}
```